# Miniprofiler (Asp.net Core) Using sessionStorage for Basic Auth

Tags: profiling, basic-authentication, session-storage, mvc-mini-profiler, miniprofiler

I am trying to use Miniprofiler on an Asp.Net Core back end. The front end is a SPA and using session storage to set basic auth. I am running into a problem where I need to set the basic auth from session storage for the mini profiler ui to load.

Is there any way to achieve this with the default ui in mini profiler? Can I override or modify the view it uses to load this attribute from session storage?

The documentation and examples are quite sparse on details.

Comment: When you say "from session storage" which piece are you trying to override? The getters for whether a person is authorized and what their user ID is take a request and allow for any logic you wish for example. With some more info on what's being asked I could probably help :)

Comment: @NickCraver my angular app uses session storage and not cookies to store the auth info. I need to manually add it to each request. Angular supports some kind of override to perform these operations. However, mini-profiler front end doesn't  have a similar feature